# KeyPressEvent works crookedly in QLable

Tags: c++, qt

I have a class that inherits QLabel. And it has keyPressEvent called, only after clicking on Tab

```
enum ElemntType { tBall, tWall, tGate, tPacman, tGhost, tWeakGhost, tPowerBall };
enum Dir { Left, Right, Up, Down, Stop }; 

class PacMan : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit PacMan();
    ~PacMan() = default;
private:
    QMovie anim;
    Dir dir;
    ElementType type;
    int x, y;
private:
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event);
};
```

and cpp file with it

```
PacMan::PacMan()
    : QLabel(), type(type), dir(Stop)
{ 
    setFocus();

    anim.setFileName("../Texture/startPacman.png");
    anim.start();
    setMovie(&anim);
    setFixedSize(20, 20);
    
    x = pos().x();
    y = pos().y();
}

void PacMan::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event)
{
    switch (event->nativeVirtualKey())
    {
    case Qt::Key_A:
        dir = Left;
        
        anim.stop();
        anim.setFileName("../Texture/lPacman.gif");
        anim.start();

        move(--x, y);
        break;
    case Qt::Key_D:
        dir = Right;

        anim.stop();
        anim.setFileName("../Texture/rPacman.gif");
        anim.start();

        move(++x, y);
        break;
    }
}
```

When I try to press keys nothing happens (keyPressEvent is not called at all), but if I press Tab then keyPressEvent will work fine. Why is this happening and how to fix it?

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QGraphicsView view(new QGraphicsScene);
    PacMan* move = new PacMan();
    move->setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);
    view.scene()->addWidget(move);
    view.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Maybe your label is not in the focus and pressing Tab key moves the focus to it?

Comment: @vahancho I've added main.cpp to the question and it's like I'm putting the focus on the PacMan object.

Comment: Well, try to call `move->setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);` after showing the view, because the focus might be changed when you add the label to the view.

Comment: it didn't work out that way, but I replaced setFocusPolicy with setFocus and called after view.show() and it worked. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `Qt::StrongFocus`, your widget is made focus-able using `tab` and `mouse`. However, it does not necessarily get the focus. One way to force it is to set `Qt::NoFocus` for all other widgets before setting your `Qt::StrongFocus`. It can be done with (taken from the answer to: [How to set Focus on a specific widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548174/how-to-set-focus-on-a-specific-widget)):

```
for (auto widget : findChildren<QWidget*>())
    if (! qobject_cast<QOpenGlWidget*>(widget)) widget->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);
```

Comment: Thanks but I already decided

Answer (score 0):

I just called setFocus together after view.show()

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QGraphicsView view(new QGraphicsScene);
    PacMan* move = new PacMan();
    view.scene()->addWidget(move);
    view.show();
    move->setFocus();
    return app.exec();
}
```